# I have created a small book program, I am new to java. Can't find what the error or mistake in this code?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class BookInfo {
  String ISBN;
  String BookName;
  String AuthorName;
  String TotalBooks;

  //parameterized constructor
  //public (){}

  public BookInfo(String i,String b,String a){
    ISBN =i ; BookName=b; AuthorName=a;
  }

  ArrayList<BookInfo>books;
  //constructor
  public BookInfo(){

    books=new ArrayList<BookInfo>();
    loadbooks();
  }

  public void loadbooks(){
    String tokens[] = null;
    String no, name, author;

    try {
      FileReader fr = new FileReader("books.txt");
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

      String line = br.readLine();

      while ( line != null ) {

        tokens = line.split(",");
        no = tokens[0];
        name = tokens[1];
        author = tokens[2];
        BookInfo  b = new BookInfo(no, name, author);
        books.add(b);
        line = br.readLine();
      }

      br.close();
      fr.close();
    }catch(IOException ioEx){
      System.out.println(ioEx);
    }
  }

public void savebooks ( ){
  try {
    BookInfo  b;

    String line;
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("books.txt");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

    for(int i=0; i < books.size(); i++){
      b = (BookInfo)books.get(i);
      line = b.ISBN +","+ b.BookName +","+ b.AuthorName;
      // writes line to file (books.txt)
      pw.println(line);
    }
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
    fw.close();
  } catch(IOException ioEx){
    System.out.println(ioEx);
  }
}

//add new book record to arraylist after taking input
public void addbook( ) {
  String ISBN = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter ISBN");
  String BookName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Book Name"); 
  String AuthorName=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Author Name");
  //construct new book object
  BookInfo  p = new BookInfo (ISBN, BookName, AuthorName);
  //add the above BookInfo  object to arraylist
  books.add(p);
}

//search book record by name by iterating over arraylist
public void searchBook (String n) {

  for (int i=0; i< books.size(); i++) {
    BookInfo  p = (BookInfo)books.get(i);
    if ( n.equals(p.AuthorName) ) {
      p.print();
    }
  } 

//delete book record by name by iterating over arraylist
public void deleteBook (String n) {
  for (int i=0; i< books.size(); i++) {
   BookInfo  p = (BookInfo)books.get(i);
   if ( n.equals(p.name) ) {
     p.remove();
   }
  }
}
} // end class
}

class BookMgtSys {

  public static void main (String args[]) {
    BookInfo p = new BookInfo();
    String input, s;
    int ch;
    while (true) {
      input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 1 to add " + "\n Enter 2 to             Search \n Enter 3 to Delete" +"\n Enter 4 to Exit");
      ch = Integer.parseInt(input);
      switch (ch) {
        case 1:
          p.addbook();
          break;
        case 2:
          s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Enter name to search ");
          p.searchBook(s);
          break;
        case 3:
          s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Enter name to delete ");
          p.deleteBook(s);
          break;
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }//end while
}//end main
}
```

This program just take book name,edit and delete option. But when I compile it gives me errors as shown below:

```
Process started >>>

BookMgtSys.java:92: error: illegal start of expression
public void deleteBook (String n) {
^

BookMgtSys.java:92: error: illegal start of expression
public void deleteBook (String n) {
^

BookMgtSys.java:92: error: ';' expected
public void deleteBook (String n) {
^

BookMgtSys.java:92: error: ';' expected
public void deleteBook (String n) {
^

4 errors
```

<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)

Comment: Errors of this type usually mean that you forgot or misplaced a brace `}` somewhere.  Proper indenting makes these kinds of errors much easier to spot.

Comment: As it stands, the code you have posted is basically illegible. If this is not a product of copy/paste issues into SO, I would highly recommend you follow the Java style guide for indentation as it would help you spot simple issues like this  in the future.

Comment: The error tells you the problem, the file, even the line number. What part doesn't make sense?

Comment: It's my 2nd day on learning java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had bracket problems. Also if you want to run your main you will have to move the main outside of the BookMgrSys class. The following code will allow you to run the application.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class BookInfo
{
    String ISBN;
    String BookName;
    String AuthorName;
    String TotalBooks;

    // parameterized constructor
    // public (){}

    public BookInfo(String i, String b, String a)
    {
        ISBN = i;
        BookName = b;
        AuthorName = a;
    }

    ArrayList<BookInfo> books;

    // constructor
    public BookInfo()
    {

        books = new ArrayList<BookInfo>();
        loadbooks();
    }

    public void loadbooks()
    {
        String tokens[] = null;
        String no, name, author;
        try
        {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("books.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line = br.readLine();
            while(line != null)
            {
                tokens = line.split(",");
                no = tokens[0];
                name = tokens[1];
                author = tokens[2];
                BookInfo b = new BookInfo(no, name, author);
                books.add(b);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            br.close();
            fr.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioEx)
        {
            System.out.println(ioEx);
        }
    }

    public void savebooks()
    {
        try
        {
            BookInfo b;

            String line;
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("books.txt");
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
            for(int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++)
            {
                b = (BookInfo) books.get(i);
                line = b.ISBN + "," + b.BookName + "," + b.AuthorName;
                // writes line to file (books.txt)
                pw.println(line);
            }
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            fw.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioEx)
        {
            System.out.println(ioEx);
        }
    }

    // add new book record to arraylist after taking input
    public void addbook()
    {
        String ISBN = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter ISBN");
        String BookName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Book Name");
        String AuthorName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Author Name");
        // construct new book object
        BookInfo p = new BookInfo(ISBN, BookName, AuthorName);
        // add the above BookInfo object to arraylist
        books.add(p);
    }

    // search book record by name by iterating over arraylist
    public void searchBook(String n)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++)
        {
            BookInfo p = (BookInfo) books.get(i);
            if(n.equals(p.AuthorName))
            {
                p.print();
            }
        }
    }

    // delete book record by name by iterating over arraylist

    public void deleteBook(String n)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++)
        {
            BookInfo p = (BookInfo) books.get(i);
            if(n.equals(p.BookName))
            {
                // p.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    public void print()
    {
        // print your book here
    }

    class BookMgtSys
    {
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        BookInfo p = new BookInfo();
        String input, s;
        int ch;
        while(true)
        {
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "Enter 1 to add " + "\n Enter 2 to             Search \n Enter 3 to Delete" + "\n Enter 4 to Exit");
            ch = Integer.parseInt(input);
            switch(ch)
            {
            case 1:
                p.addbook();
                break;
            case 2:
                s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name to search ");
                p.searchBook(s);
                break;
            case 3:
                s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name to delete ");
                p.deleteBook(s);
                break;
            }
        } // end while
    }// end main
} // end class
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You have forgotten the closing curly brace of the `searchBook` method. Add a `}` right before the comment `//delete book ...`
2. You have an extra closing curly brace right after `// end class`
3. You have forgotten closing curly brace for `BookMgtSys`
4. On the code in the question `class BookInfo` doesn't have methods `remove` or `print`. Quite naturally the compiler complains about it. Also there is no field `name`

Most importantly make sure you format and indent your code. Such syntax errors will become more obvious if the source code is formatted and indented

Comment: Now getting this error:

BookMgtSys.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
p.print();
 ^
  symbol:   method print()
  location: variable p of type BookInfo
BookMgtSys.java:95: error: cannot find symbol
if ( n.equals(p.name) ) {
               ^
  symbol:   variable name
  location: variable p of type BookInfo
BookMgtSys.java:96: error: cannot find symbol
p.remove();
 ^
  symbol:   method remove()
  location: variable p of type BookInfo

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, use some [IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/). Notepad++ is not what you want. Herebelow is pretty-printed and fixed version of your code, however you still need to work through it.

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;

    class BookInfo {
        String ISBN;
        String BookName;
        String AuthorName;
        String TotalBooks;

    //parameterized constructor
    //public (){}

        public BookInfo(String i, String b, String a) {
            ISBN = i;
            BookName = b;
            AuthorName = a;
        }

        ArrayList<BookInfo> books;

        //constructor
        public BookInfo() {

            books = new ArrayList<BookInfo>();
            loadbooks();
        }

        public void loadbooks() {
            String tokens[] = null;
            String no, name, author;
            try {
                FileReader fr = new FileReader("books.txt");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                String line = br.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    tokens = line.split(",");
                    no = tokens[0];
                    name = tokens[1];
                    author = tokens[2];
                    BookInfo b = new BookInfo(no, name, author);
                    books.add(b);
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
                br.close();
                fr.close();
            } catch (IOException ioEx) {
                System.out.println(ioEx);
            }
        }

        public void savebooks() {
            try {
                BookInfo b;

                String line;
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("books.txt");
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
                for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {
                    b = (BookInfo) books.get(i);
                    line = b.ISBN + "," + b.BookName + "," + b.AuthorName;
    // writes line to file (books.txt)
                    pw.println(line);
                }
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
                fw.close();
            } catch (IOException ioEx) {
                System.out.println(ioEx);
            }
        }

        //add new book record to arraylist after taking input
        public void addbook() {
            String ISBN = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter ISBN");
            String BookName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Book Name");
            String AuthorName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Author Name");
    //construct new book object
            BookInfo p = new BookInfo(ISBN, BookName, AuthorName);
    //add the above BookInfo  object to arraylist
            books.add(p);
        }

        //search book record by name by iterating over arraylist
        public void searchBook(String n) {
            for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {
                BookInfo p = (BookInfo) books.get(i);
                if (n.equals(p.AuthorName)) {
                    p.print();
                }
            }
        }

    //delete book record by name by iterating over arraylist

        public void deleteBook(String n) {
            for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {
                BookInfo p = (BookInfo) books.get(i);
                if (n.equals(p.BookName)) {
    //                p.remove();
                }
            }
        }

        public void print() {
            // print your book here
        }

    } // end class


    class BookMgtSys {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            BookInfo p = new BookInfo();
            String input, s;
            int ch;
            while (true) {
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 1 to add " + "\n Enter 2 to             Search \n Enter 3 to Delete" + "\n Enter 4 to Exit");
                ch = Integer.parseInt(input);
                switch (ch) {
                    case 1:
                        p.addbook();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name to search ");
                        p.searchBook(s);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name to delete ");
                        p.deleteBook(s);
                        break;
                }
            }//end while
        }//end main
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much @jdevelop . Thumbs up for you. I have netbean too.

Comment: @jdevelop: would have been more reasonable to edit the original question and add the properly indented code there - would have saved me some time **and** it wouldn't clutter the question.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg well, sorry about that, I haven't modified any post that is not mine, and actualy didn't know that is even possible. Thanks for the hint :)